# Batch script to delete specific folders

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, script

I want to be able to run a script at a parent folder that contains other folders, the script will delete all the folders of a certain name.

So for example to remove all the bin folders and only them: `\parent\a\bin`, `\parent\a\subfolder\bin`, `\parent\b\bin`.

I found a similar script here, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for /d /r %%i in (bin) do @rmdir /s %%i
```

We probably need to empty the `bin` folder first and then remove it, how can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The script will delete all the folders of a certain name

You don't need to empty the directory as the `rd` option `/s` will do that for you.

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem find directories called bin
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d bin`) do (
  rem delete the directories and any files or subdirectories
  rd /s /q "%%i"
  )
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).

Comment: Very cool, just to make sure I got it, does it go through a list of folders, matching each item with the last keyword (bin)?

Comment: The `dir` finds all folders with the name bin and the `for` loops through them one by one for deletion.