# Delete specific folders at UNC location

Tags: batch, script, unc

I'm trying to create a batch script to delete all folders having "Exception_" in it's name from the current folder in a remote desktop. I used [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1060579/batch-script-to-delete-specific-folders) to a previous question to come up with the below script.

```
  @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem find directories called Exception_
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b /s /a:d Exception_`) do (
  rem delete the directories and any files or subdirectories
  rd /s /q "%%i"
  )
endlocal
```

However, the command prompt is showing that UNC paths are not supported. Any way to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [pushd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd):

> Stores the current directory for use by the popd command, and then
>   changes to the specified directory.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> pushd [<Path>]
> ```

The command will create a temporary drive letter mapped to your UNC root
location and effectively CD to that location.

For example:

```
@echo off
pushd \\server\share
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it does not seem to work. I replaced the setlocal command with pushd <path>. It did create a temporary network drive but always returns a "File Not Found" prompt even when there are folders with "Exception_" in their name. The folders do not get deleted

Comment: This is a problem with the script. It should use `dir /b /s /a:d Exception_*`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But the prompt shows "The system cannot find the file '`dir /b /s /a:d Exception_*`". Am I doing something wrong here as I'm trying to delete a folder by that name and not a file? Also, where should I place the popd command exactly. I'm sorry if this is too basic but I'm kind of new to batch scripting

Comment: It works for me. Try to debug with simplified syntax such as `for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:d Exception_*') do echo %%i`.